# Вывод цвета не работает в IDLE, а в CMD работает нормально

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

Добавил комментарий к такому же вопросу. Почему в IDLE цвет не выводится, а в CMD все работает нормально?

[image: В CMD фон меняется на красный, а в IDLE выдает текст 41m]

Пример кода

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init()

print( Back.RED )

what = input ("Что делаем? (+,-,/):")

a = float(input("Введи первое число: "))
b = float(input("Введи второе число "))

if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("result " + str(c))
elif what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("result " + str(c))
elif what == "/":
    c = a / b
    print("result " + str(c))
else:
    print("не верное число")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

colorama красит термирнал с помощью [управляющих символов ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI).
Idle - это IDE с графической оболочкой и он игнорирует эти команды.

Comment: Что характерно, cmd не поддерживает управляющие ansi последовательности. colorama сама эмулирует эту поддержку под windows.